# Vagrant, Codeception & Laravel issue. NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, codeception

I'm trying to get into using [codeception](http://codeception.com) for my acceptance testing.

I have the following for one of my tests:

```
<?php
use Codeception\Util\Stub;

class SomeTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{

    protected $webGuy;

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function incorrect_login_should_redirect_back()
    {
        $I = $this->webGuy;
        $I->wantTo('fail at logging in');
        $I->amOnPage('/'); // <-- This is the line that is failing
        $I->fillField('email','info@tntstudio.hr');
        $I->fillField('password','pass');
        $I->click('Login');
        $I->see('email', 'input');
        $I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/login');
    }

}
```

Initially the tests ran OK, however after adding `Laravel4` to the `acceptance.suite.yml` file and running `build`, the test now fails with the following:

```
1) SomeTest::incorrect_login_should_redirect_back
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: 

#1  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:1021
#2  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:989
#3  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:968
#4  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:738
#5  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:708
#6  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
#7  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:325
#8  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/app/tests/acceptance/WebGuy.php:476
#9  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/hired/app/tests/acceptance/SomeTest.php:16
```

I'm running my app in a virtual environment using vagrant, at `http://localhost:3030/`

I have set this to the url for the `PhpBrowser` config in `acceptance.suite.yml` as below:

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled:
        - PhpBrowser
        - WebHelper
        - Laravel4
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost:3030/'
```

I'm wondering if anybody else has come across this, or has any ideas on how to get around this, I've been tearing my hair out for hours on this.

Comment: I run a similar setup to you, but in my acceptance suite I only have enabled PhpBroweser, WebHelper and DB. I dont use the Laravel4 modules, do you need them for your acceptance tests?

Comment: I don't **need** them per se and no doubt could get away without using the Laravel4 module, but would like to use the methods it provides.

Comment: Maybe put a debug log on the routes file, and see what route it is actually 'trying' to hit to generate the http exception? I think the fact your are getting the symfony exception means you are at least 'hitting' your application with the test?

Comment: Does your `config/app/app.php` file have the right URL set up? You may find you need the full URL with the `:3030` too.

Comment: @alexrussell yeah I tried that, didn't help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was not able to find a solution to this, so for now am going to just go without the `Laravel4` module, sadly.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I've posted a new answer for you.

Answer (score 5):

Laravel4 module will cause Codeception to use the "testing" environment in Laravel.

Laravel will disable all route filters in "testing" environment - so your filters are not working correctly and its probably calling the wrong route, causing your app to die and your test to fail.

I dont think using the Laravel4 module with "acceptance" tests is correct - it should only be for functional tests? *Edit: I just found that the Codeception Laravel4 module docs actually say "This module allows you to run functional tests for Laravel 4" - so I guess it was not actually designed for Acceptance tests?*

But with all the changes in Codeception 2.x - you are better off using PhpBrowser module for your *acceptance* tests, and Laravel4 module for your *functional* tests.

If you are using Homestead, I do this in my `start.php` file to detect if Codeception is running, and specifically put it into a 'codeception' environment, otherwise I let it run my environment detection normally

```
if ((gethostname() === 'homestead') && (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) && ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] === '127.0.0.1'))
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['codeception' => ['homestead']]);
}
else
{
    $env = $app->detectEnvironment(['dev' => ['homestead']]);
}
```

Then in my 'codeception' environment, I setup a SQLite file database, and run acceptance tests against that (which is faster than mySQL testing).

Comment: Very nice answer ! This should be mandatory in codeception doc

Comment: @The Shift Exchange Can you help me with this? https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2276

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to change your `start.php`. You can set the environment for codecption in the laravel4 Module config. So in your `acceptance.suite.yml` it will look like this:

`modules:
    enabled: [PhpBrowser, WebHelper, Laravel4]
    config:
        Laravel4:
            environment : 'codeception'
            filters : true`

Now, when you execute `php codecept run acceptance` in your terminal, the Laravel4 Module will use the configuration files from `app/config/codeception`.