# Indicate application to use different database when running Codeception acceptance test

Tags: codeception

The application i am planning to test runs on Database say for example named "main". When using codeception, i want the application to use "main_test" database. The application database name is in a php define. I thought initially i can set the define to main_test in the acceptance test bootstrap and the application will be automatically will be aware of it. I think since codeception creates a new session,, the define which i set, is not being used.

So my question is what is a way to indicate my application that it needs to use different database name when codeception access it.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24096862/1317935

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation - http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Db

```
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=project_qa'
            user: 'user_qa'
            password: '1234567'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
```

Please notice if you write tests that use PhpBrowser, Selenium, etc you will need configure separate access point in your application that will use correct DB.
For example in SF2 application we use such construction in codeception config

```
   PhpBrowser:
        url: 'http://project.dev/app_local_test.php'
```