# Can't run Auth::loginUsingId(1) in Codeception acceptance _bootstrap.php

Tags: php, laravel, codeception

I'm using Laravel and Codeception to do acceptance testing. Most of my tests require users to be logged in, so I wanted to extract those behaviours to the _bootstrap.php file inside the acceptance folder. I understand this is the practice for running setup prior to your tests, in Codeception.

I can confirm that my users table exists (I'm viewing it using Navicat), and that a user with an id of 1 exists. Codeception, to the best of my knowledge, is properly configured to use this database. I also have included the Laravel4 and Db modules for the acceptance suite. I receive the following error when I try to run my acceptance suite, or any individual acceptance Cept.

**console**:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from "users" where "id" = $1 limit 1
                      ^ (SQL: select * from "users" where "id" = 1 limit 1)
```

I get this error regardless of the contents of any of the acceptance Cepts. Even a simple `$I->amOnPage('/')`, or `$I->comment('test')` still results in the error. I believe the error occurs as soon as it encounters the command in the _bootstrap.php file. Somehow it's able to access my database. I should note that I've also tried various combinations of enabling and disabling the populate and cleanup settings for the Laravel4 and Db modules, to no avail.

Here is my **acceptance/_bootstrap.php** file:

```
<?php

Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

**codeception.yml:**

```
actor: Tester
paths:
    tests: tests
    log: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    helpers: tests/_support
settings:
    bootstrap: _bootstrap.php
    colors: true
    memory_limit: 1024M
modules:
    config:
        Db:
            dsn: 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=myapp'
            user: 'someuser'
            password: 'somepass'
            dump: tests/_data/dump.sql
```

**acceptance.suite.yml:**

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - AcceptanceHelper
        - Laravel4
        - PhpBrowser
        - Db
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost'
        Laravel4:
            cleanup: false
        Db:
            populate: true
            cleanup: false
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should not use `Laravel4` module for Codeception *acceptance* tests. It is only for *functional* and *unit* tests. [See this answer for more info on this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24096862/1317935)

To answer your specific question about automatically logging in your user on your acceptance tests - this is how I do it:

**/tests/_support/AcceptanceHelper.php**

```
<?php
namespace Codeception\Module;
use \AcceptanceTester;

class AcceptanceHelper extends \Codeception\Module
{
    // This is my default user I use for all my tests
    public function loginUser(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {
        $this->login($i, 'user@test.com', 'tester');
    }  

    // And this function lets me login a specific user if I need someone else
    public function login(AcceptanceTester $i, $email, $password)
    {
        $i->amOnPage('/login');
        $i->fillField('email', $email);
        $i->fillField('password', $password);
        $i->click('submit');
        $i->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/dashboard');
    }

    public function logoutUser(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {
        $i->amOnPage('/logout');
        $i->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/login');
        $i->see('You have been logged out');
    }
}
```

**/tests/acceptance/ExampleCest.php**

```
<?php
use \AcceptanceTester;

class ExampleCest
{
    public function _before(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {
        $i->loginUser($i);
    }


    public function tryToViewDashboard(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {   
        // User is logged in here 
        $i->amOnPage('/dashboard');
    }

    public function tryOtherExample(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {   
        // User is logged in here 
        $i->amOnPage('/dashboard');
    }

    public function tryMoreInfo(AcceptanceTester $i)
    {   
        // User is logged in here 
        $i->amOnPage('/dashboard');
    }
}
```

Note: I use a smallcase `$i` instead of `$I` - I find it easier to type - so you might need to change all the `$i` to `$I` in your code